# finding rows against summed value of specific id's in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql

I have a table like below--

```
Id| Amount|DateAdded  |
--|-------|-----------|
1   20     20-Jun-2018
1   10     05-Jun-2018
1   4      21-May-2018
1   5      15-May-2018
1   15     05-May-2018
2   25     15-Jun-2018
2   25     12-Jun-2018
2   65     05-Jun-2018
2   65     20-May-2018
```

Here If I sum up the Amount of Id = 1 then I will get 54 as the sum result. I want to find those rows of Id = 1 whose sum is not greater then exact 35 or any given value

In case of given value 35 the expected Output for id = 1 should be--

```
    Id| Amount|DateAdded  |
    --|-------|-----------|
    1   20     20-Jun-2018
    1   10     05-Jun-2018
    1   4      21-May-2018
    1   5      15-May-2018
```

In case of given value 50 the expected Output for Id = 2 should be--

```
  Id| Amount|DateAdded  |
  --|-------|-----------|
   2   25     15-Jun-2018
   2   25     12-Jun-2018
```

Comment: In your ID =1 example, the amounts sum to 39. But you specify 35 as maximum?

Comment: Also if I am understanding you correctly, there are multiple correct answers. So the sum of the rows 20 and 10 has sum 30, which is not greater than 35. Or any single row would also satisfy your requirement. Or Any pair of rows. Or 20+10+4, or 20+10+5.

Comment: @DanielEarwicker to get sum of 35 it needs to use row number 4.

Comment: You mean it needs to use `20+10+5`? So why does your example output also include `4`?

Answer (score 2):

You would use a cumulative sum.  To get all the rows:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             sum(amount) over (partition by id order by dateadded) as running_amount
      from t
     ) t
where t.running_amount - amount < 35;
```

To get just the row that passes the mark:

```
where t.running_amount - amount < 35 and
      t.running_amount >= 35
```